# How to test ModelBinders in ASP.Net Mvc 3

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I'm trying to write some tests for a custom modelbinder and my god is this turning out difficult to stub. None of the stuff I'm finding online relates directly to ASP.Net Mvc 3 or tends to have very incomplete examples.

Specifically, the biggest wall I'm hitting is with bindingContext.ModelType - setting it explcitly throws an (runtime) error that the setter is obsoleted and that it is inferred from the Model parameter but the Model parameter for me is and should be null!

Answer (score 0):

Hanselman explains this in great detail here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx

Update: The above sample is obsolete. Read the comments on this post!

Comment: Actually I don't think that it is obsolete. Maybe some of the initial stuff, but the unit test code still works, right?

Comment: ValueProviderDictionary is obsolete and it gets worse from there. Stuff isn't bound quite the same way anymore and things like ModelType cannot be set directly at all. I couldn't get my scenario (to load a model from a mock db or create a new one) working at all with this pattern.

Comment: Just played around with it. You're completely right. The API has really been messed up in the recent version of MVC. You can't set the ModelType anymore. I found out that the ModelType is now taken from the ModelMetadata property, which you can set. ModelMetadata takes a model type parameter in its constructor and I think this is what you want to set. But when I run my test, I get a NullReferenceException in UnvalidatedValueProviderWrapper.GetValue(String key). I don't know how to fix this though :(

Comment: It's really sad, that the model binders are no longer easily testable. One way would be to make a new type in the test, extending your model binder with a public method calling the protected CreateModel method. But that's a pretty nasty solution if you ask me. Sorry for misleading you with the blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas & George, you have to set the value provider on the ModelBindingContext.  Below is an example of code in my HomeController Index action that creates a type and uses the default model binder to hydrate the object.  This is just a simplified version, in my production code I actually take a param into the controller action that is the type and then create the type dynamically on the fly, works great when you want to send more than one type to a single controller action.  Notice that ValueProvider and ControllerContext are properties of the controller.

```
        HomeModel test = new HomeModel();
        ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => test, test.GetType());
        ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext { ModelMetadata = metadata, ValueProvider = ValueProvider};


        DefaultModelBinder defaultModelBinder = new DefaultModelBinder();
        defaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext, modelBindingContext);
```

Comment: Hmm, but you're picking the ValueProvider from Controller - this is not available in a unit test. It's been a while but I seem to remember trying to create a ValueProvider and failing because it required a lot of complex parameters.  I have tried to look through the ASP MVC source unit tests and it seems like they're relying on the fact that ASP MVC exposes some classes directly to the unit tests using InternalsVisibleTo

Comment: You should take a look at this post to create your own ValueProviderFactories.http://blog.approache.com/2011/03/unit-test-actions-with.html